# Matrix change fun

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

a matrix with which I am working looks like this

```
m <- matrix(rep(c(0,1),10),ncol=2,nrow=5)
colnames(m)<-c(2,5)
```

so the matrix has rows at pos 2 and 5. All pos which are not in colnames need to be all 0

```
        2    5
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    1    0
[5,]    0    1
```

should then be

```
        1 2 3 4 5
[1,]    0 0 0 0 1
[2,]    0 1 0 0 0
[3,]    0 0 0 0 1
[4,]    0 1 0 0 0
[5,]    0 0 0 0 1
```

the function would need to take in an end paramter (at this example it is 5)

Is there a solution which is fast in very larg matrix? I talk about 1400 times 10 Mil oder something like this

Answer (score 1):

We create a square `matrix` of '0' based on the maximum value of the column name in the initial matrix ('m1').  In the example, it is '5'.  So, the 'm2', we created is of dimension `5X5`.

```
n <- max(as.numeric(colnames(m1)))
m2 <- matrix(0, n,n)
```

Using `melt` from `reshape2`, we convert the 'wide' format of 'm1' to 'long' format, `subset` the resulting 'data.frame' by removing the rows where 'value' is '0'.  Create the row/column index based on the first and second column, convert it to `matrix` and use that for replacing the '0' value in 'm2' to 1.

```
library(reshape2)
m2[as.matrix(subset(melt(m1), value!=0)[,-3])] <- 1
m2
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be creating the row/column index without the `melt`, `cbind` the row/column index and replace the values in 'm2' to 1.

```
 m2[cbind(seq(n), c(as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1))] <- 1
```

EDIT:

If the values are not all 1 in 'm1'

```
 m2[cbind(seq(n), c(as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1))] <- m1[!!m1]
```

Just for easier understanding, the above code can be split up into different parts. `col(m1)` gives the column index of the original matrix.

```
 col(m1)
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    1    2
 #[2,]    1    2
 #[3,]    1    2
 #[4,]    1    2
 #[5,]    1    2
```

By using that numeric index, we can change that values to the column names of 'm1' after converting to 'numeric'.  The output is a `vector`.

```
 as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]
 #[1] 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5
```

Multiplying with 'm1' replaces the '1' values with the values we got in the above step

```
as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1
#     2 5
#[1,] 0 5
#[2,] 2 0
#[3,] 0 5
#[4,] 2 0
#[5,] 0 5
```

We can concatenate (`c`) it to a `vector` to create the column index

```
 c(as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1)
 #[1] 0 2 0 2 0 5 0 5 0 5
```

Get the `seq` of 'n' for the 'row' index.

```
 seq(n)
 #[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

When we `cbind` the row index with the column index, due to the recycling, the row index repeats itself to the length of the column index

```
  cbind(seq(n),  c(as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1))
  #     [,1] [,2]
  #[1,]    1    0
  #[2,]    2    2
  #[3,]    3    0
  #[4,]    4    2
  #[5,]    5    0
  #[6,]    1    5
  #[7,]    2    0
  #[8,]    3    5
  #[9,]    4    0
  #[10,]   5    5
```

This can be used for getting the corresponding elements from 'm2'

```
   m2[cbind(seq(n), c(as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1))]
   #[1] 0 0 0 0 0
```

which we are assigning to 1

In the EDIT part, I used `!!m1`, which returns logical matrix `TRUE/FALSE` for all values that are not 0. By subsetting `m1[!!m1]`, we get a `vector` of those values and can be used for replacement.

---

Or a faster approach will be creating a `sparseMatrix` using the `library(Matrix)`.  As described above, we create the row ('i') and the column ('j') index, subset the 'i' and 'j' to include only non-zero values (as it won't work with `sparseMatrix`), and specify `x=1`.  Here, we don't have to create an initial matrix 'm2'.

```
 library(Matrix)
 j <- c(as.numeric(colnames(m1))[col(m1)]*m1)
 i <- rep(seq(n), length.out=length(j))
 sparseMatrix(i[j!=0], j[j!=0], x=1)
 #   5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

 #[1,] . . . . 1
 #[2,] . 1 . . .
 #[3,] . . . . 1
 #[4,] . 1 . . .
 #[5,] . . . . 1
```

Wrapping with `as.matrix` converts it to regular matrix

```
  as.matrix(sparseMatrix(i[j!=0], j[j!=0], x=1))
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  #[1,]    0    0    0    0    1
  #[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
  #[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
  #[4,]    0    1    0    0    0
  #[5,]    0    0    0    0    1
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(rep(c(0,1),10),ncol=2,nrow=5)
colnames(m1) <- c(2,5)
```

Comment: could you explain the last bit...why [,-3]? is it working on general or only on this exampl?

Comment: @kagh It should work in general cases.  Can you try on another example.

Comment: so the square matrix would be in a case of 1000 cols 1000 times 1000? I just think it is not working if the set if very large like the thing described in the q..a 10e6 t 10e6 matrix....?

Comment: @kagh Can you try the `sparseMatrix` approach.  It should be faster

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar solution without melting the matrix.

First we will take the value from the last column and allocate a matrix (similar to @akruns approach)

```
indx <- as.numeric(colnames(m)[ncol(m)])
m2 <- matrix(0, ncol = indx, nrow = nrow(m))
```

Then, we will simply add column names to the new matrix and insert the old matrix according to the matching column names

```
colnames(m2) <- seq_len(indx)
m2[, colnames(m)] <- m
m2
#      1 2 3 4 5
# [1,] 0 0 0 0 1
# [2,] 0 1 0 0 0
# [3,] 0 0 0 0 1
# [4,] 0 1 0 0 0
# [5,] 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: @akrun Your update is quite different because you are always assuming that all the values are equal to 1, while I have no assumptions on the data

Comment: @kagh what us "scale of the matrix"? What's wrong with it?